# Problem installing gfortran

Tags: apt

I have just installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my computer, then tried to install `gfortran` using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran
```

in a terminal and it says:

```
E: Unable to locate package gfortran
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update` yet? Try it and then repeat the command.

Answer (score 2):

To install gfortran, make sure that universe repository is checked, and then

[image]

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install gfortran
```

Or you can just install it from the USC or by clicking on the image below:

[image: Install via the software center]