# +problems with apt-get

Tags: apt, python

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit on my computer. I would like to install a F.E.M solver named Code_Aster but i need to install the following dependencies before this:

```
gfortran, g++, python-dev, python-numpy, python-qt4, zlib1g-dev, liblapack-dev, libblas-dev, tk, grace, bison and finally flex
```

I tried to run the following command to get them :

```
sudo apt-get install \
gfortran g++ \
python-dev python-numpy python-qt4 \
zlib1g-dev liblapack-dev libblas-dev \
tk grace bison flex
```

But it did not work. As the output of the terminal was rather long I tried to install them one by one and get the following messages :

```
[sudo] password for redg: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gfortran
```

to solve this I already read : [this discussion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292721/problem-installing-gfortran) and tried to install gfortran "munally" [with this file](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/gfortran) but I failed in both ways.

For python-numpy I get the following

```
redg@OkDesu:~$ sudo apt-get install python-numpy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-numpy
```

If found [this](http://www.andrewsturges.com/2012/05/installing-numpy-16-on-python-27-in.html) on the internet but it did not help much. It only confirmed the module was not installed.

As I get similar errors with the other libraries I suggest we just focus on gfortran for now.

Thank you in advance for your help !

Edit1: I failed to mention I failed to mention i'm using a proxy but everything seems to be fine on this side. This is what i found in the apt.conf file :`Acquire::http::proxy "http://150.73.3.41:80/";`

Comment: Try using `sudo apt-get update`, then installing after

Comment: Thanks for replying DaboRoss. In fact I already tried that as well as :
'code' sudo aptitude -o Acquire::http::No-Cache=True -o Acquire::BrokenProxy=true update
sudo apt-get update 'code'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always try a

```
sudo apt-cache search "package-name"
```

to see if the package has been named differently in the repository

Comment: Thank you very much, I just tried it and seems to be working. It seems like **I have to specify the version if I want apt-get to work.**
I feel stupid for not thinking about it... I will mark this Solved as soon as I am done. Thank you again for your help

Comment: Everything has been working fine since gfortran has been isntalled. 'apt-get install python-numpy' even worked without having to write anything elee. I'm not really sure what happened. Anyway case closed. Thank you all for replying.